# How to convert rows to columns using CSS?

Tags: html, css, ionic3

I'm developing a Web Application in Ionic3 framework. In my table Each item is available in different sizes.
On mobile devices, the screen is too narrow to properly display up to 4 different sizes item.

So I would like to convert rows into columns in Mobile view only.

Let's take this Example

### Input-

### x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5

### y1 | y2 | y3 | y4 | y5

### z1 | z2 | z3 | z4 | z5

### Output-

### x1  |  y1 | z1

### x2  |  y2 | z2

### x3  |  y3 | z3

### x4  |  y4 | z4

### x5  |  y5 | z5

Is there a way of doing this in CSS?

Comment: If you use "table" you can't. But possible using css grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @Divya Could you please provide your table's HTML?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `display: flex`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  tr {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>x1</td>
    <td>x2</td>
    <td>x3</td>
    <td>x4</td>
    <td>x5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>y1</td>
    <td>y2</td>
    <td>y3</td>
    <td>y4</td>
    <td>y5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>z1</td>
    <td>z2</td>
    <td>z3</td>
    <td>z4</td>
    <td>z5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code works when viewport width is less than 500px.

Comment: Should set `table` and `td` to be `display: block;` to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using HTML and css

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  table tr>* {
    display: block;
  }
  table tr {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
    <th>Head 3</th>
    <th>Head 4</th>
    <th>Head 5</th>
    <th>Head 6</th>
    <th>Head 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 4</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 5</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 6</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```