# How can i position the table head on the left of table body with css only

Tags: css, tr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7DCw.png)
Hello, how can i get this effect, where the th's and td's are seemingly in one row? Here is the HTML

```css
@media (max-width:360px){
    thead {
        float: left
    }
    th{
        display: block;
    }
    tbody {
        float: right
    }
    td{
        margin: 0px;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Matman</td>
        <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jon</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Eater</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my current try but it is nowhere near the result i need

Comment: try `tr {display: inline-flex;flex-direction: column;}` Other similar SO questions:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974080/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-using-css#) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010337/show-table-as-columns-on-mobile-and-as-rows-on-desktop) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903081/css-display-column-as-row-in-mobile-view)

Comment: but since you need to repeat the header I think you'll need javascript.. never went that far

Comment: you are care about that the head is wrapped inside th tags?

Comment: Use a table with two columns and no header, and use the first column as the label (e.g. First Name, Last Name, ...).

Answer (score 0):

What you want can only be done repeating the tr and the th which will make the code more and longer. here is your example.

if you dont want border all around, you can use: border-bottom, border-top.

```css
tr {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  td , th{
    padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid black; 
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you should checkout out how its done using [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) and [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) Templates.
smarty:

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {foreach from=$data item=row}
      <tr>
        <td>{$row.col1}</td>
        <td>{$row.col2}</td>
      </tr>
    {/foreach}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Twig: using for or foreach.

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ row.col1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.col2 }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```